# number of n.t. zeros in an interval in the limit

Tags: riemann-zeta, riemann-hypothesis

**Motivation:**

We know that the density of non-trivial zeros of $\zeta(s)$ increases with $t$. But how dense does it get? Assuming RH.

**Summary**

1. Trying to solve for number of zeros in the length (measured in $t$) of one cycle of $\cos\nu(t)$.
2. $\frac{dN(t)}{dt}$ gives me number of zeros per interval $dt$. Now $\cos\nu(t)$ is periodic (locally) and so we need $d\nu(t) = 2\pi$ to find how much does $\nu(t)$ have to change to get length of one cycle of $\cos\nu(t)$. ($\cos\nu(t) = \cos(\nu(t) + 2\pi) = \cos(\nu(t) + d\nu(t))$).
3. So in $\frac{d\nu(t)}{dt}$ I plug in $d\nu(t) = 2\pi$ to give me the interval $dt$ needed to equal one cycle of $\cos\nu(t)$. Doing so, I would get $\begin{align*} dt = \frac{4\pi}{\log \frac{t}{2\pi}}\end{align*}$ which can be plugged into $\frac{dN(t)}{dt}$ giving me $dN(t)$ which is the number of zeros in an unit interval $dt$ and we also know that this $dt$ is equal to length of one cycle of $\cos\nu(t)$.

See pages 119-120 of H.M.Edwards *Riemann's Zeta Function* for reference.

\begin{align}
N(t) &= \frac{t}{2\pi} \log\left(\frac{t}{2\pi}\right)-  \frac{t}{2\pi}  + O\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)\\\\
\implies \frac {d N(t)}{dt}  &= \frac{1}{2\pi}\log{\frac{t}{2\pi}} \tag{1} \\\\
Z(t) &= e^{i\nu(t)}\zeta(\frac{1}{2} + it) \\\\
\nu(t) &= Im \log \prod\left(\frac{it}{2} - \frac{3}{4}\right) - \frac{t}{2} \log \pi \\\\
&= \frac{t}{2}\log \frac{t}{2\pi} - \frac{t}{2} -\frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{1}{48t} + \frac{7}{5760t^3} + \cdots
\end{align}

differentiating $\nu(t)$ and ignoring higher order terms of $\frac{1}{t}$  gives us:
\begin{align*}
\frac{d\nu(t)}{dt} = \frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{t}{2\pi}\right)
\end{align*}

since $\cos\nu(t) = \cos(\nu(t) + 2\pi)$,  substituting $2\pi$ for $d\nu(t)$,  we get
\begin{align*}
dt = \frac{4\pi}{\log \frac{t}{2\pi}}
\end{align*}

Substituting for $dt$ in (1), we get
\begin{align*}
\lim_{t \to \infty} dN(t) = \frac{4\pi}{\log \frac{t}{2\pi}} \frac{\log\frac{t}{2\pi}}{2\pi} = 2
\end{align*}

Let us put this to test.  In  the interval $t_1 = 30610045718.27011 \le t \le t_2 =  30610045999.548215$ there are 1000 zeros,  which implies:
\begin{align*}
\frac{dN(t)}{dt} = \frac{1000}{t_2-t_1} = 3.5552.
\end{align*}
One cycle of $\cos\nu(t)$ in this range of $t$ will have a length of
\begin{align*}
 dt = \frac{4\pi}{\log \frac{t}{2\pi}} = 0.56334. 
\end{align*}

Hence number of zeros in one cycle of $\cos\nu(t)$ is:
$dN(t) =  0.56334*3.5552 = 2.00278$.  For large $t$,  this should converge to $2$.

Similar analysis will show that even for Dirichlet L-series, $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} dN(t,\chi) = 2$.

**My Question:**
Since the Davenport-Hielbronn Zeta function has zeros on and off the CL, I am curious to know what is $\lim\limits_{t \to \infty} dN(t)$ for D-H zeta? I conjecture that this will be different from $2$. (obviously there is a $\cos\nu(t)$ equivalent for DH Zeta different from the one used above).

Comment: Karatsuba and Voronin book on RZ has an analysis of the DH function in chapter $6$ - they show that the number of zeroes on the critical line is at least $TV(T)$ with a specific $V(T) \to \infty$ and then in various papers this has been improved to something like $T (\log T)^{1/2+1/16-\epsilon}$ - but I am not sure more is known (eg an asymptotic formula like for $\zeta$)

Comment: @Conrad, is the conclusion that $\lim_{t \to \infty} dN(t) = 2$ correct? Thanks

Comment: I do not really understand what you mean by $dN(t)$ and for example what $\begin{align*}
dt = \frac{4\pi}{\log \frac{t}{2\pi}}\end{align*}$ means

Comment: Hi @Conrad, I added a summary section at top to clarify. Does that help? Thank you so much!

Comment: I kind of understand what you mean but still not get the point - to me it seems that you on one hand use something $\nu(t)$ related to the critical zeroes and on the other $N$ which are all zerors so it seems to me that you implicitly assume RH

Comment: Oh yes. I see what you are saying. So this is saying assuming RH, the density of zeros is $2$ in one cycle of $\cos\nu(t)$ in the limit.

Comment: To me the issue is that $\nu(t)$ and $Z$ count things on the critical line, while the formula for $N$ is global so mixing them (without assuming RH when of course they are the same) is kind of weird